# How to use second DispatcherServlet for resources

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, servlets

## Configuration

Servlet 3.0 on Tomcat 7.0.47
Spring 3.1

## Question

I have a somewhat special case where I need two `DispatcherServlets`: One to handle resource requests and one to handle normal `@RequestMapping`-type requests. For some reason, I'm getting this in the logs:

> No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/my-app/images/someimage.png] in DispatcherServlet with name 'resources'

Here's what my `web.xml` file looks like:

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>resources</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>resources</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/css/*</url-pattern>
  <url-pattern>/images/*</url-pattern>
  <url-pattern>/js/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet>
  <servlet-name>springmvc</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>springmvc</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

In `resources-servlet.xml` I have this:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
  xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
  xsi:schemaLocation="
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd"
  default-autowire="byName">

  <context:annotation-config />
  <context:property-placeholder />

  <mvc:resources mapping="/images/**" location="/images/"/>
  <mvc:resources mapping="/js/**" location="/js/"/>

  <context:component-scan base-package="lesscss" />
  <mvc:annotation-driven />
</beans>
```

As you can see, I have no `<mvc:resources>` for CSS files because that mapping is done with a `@Controller` building LESS files on the fly. The `<context:component-scan base-package="lesscss" />` takes care of that bit, and it seems to be working.

I previously had those `<mvc:resources>` tags in my `springmvc-servlet.xml` file, but I removed them. What else could I be missing?

**UPDATE**

I tried changing my `web.xml` file to use `*.ext` url-patterns instead of the `/dir/*` kind, and it worked. I'd rather not have to list out all the extensions, though, so I would still like a better solution to this problem.

**UPDATE**

I changed `<mvc:resources mapping="/images/**" location="/images/"/>` to `<mvc:resources mapping="/**" location="/images/"/>` and removed the one for `js` files, and the images started working. It seems the `servlet-mapping` `url-pattern` before the `*` is being ignored when mapping things in Spring. is there a way around this?

## Explanation of why I "need" two Servlets

I figured I would add this just for the sake of helping someone else who didn't realize this before (like me) and give someone an opportunity to come up with a better solution if there is one.

When using the `<mvc:resources>` tag, the handlers that are created are part of the regular `DispatcherServlet` request handling. This means that, if you don't specifically state all the resource paths that are *not* handled by `<mvc:resources>` using `<mvc:mapping>` (I am still using Spring 3.1 and cannot use `<mvc:exclude-mapping>`), every request for images, JavaScript files, and stylesheets runs all the `HandlerInterceptor`s you have listed in `<mvc:interceptors>`. I have quite a few interceptors in my application, and listing all the paths is incredibly error-prone due to the structure and nature of the app. More than just a performance hit, execution of all these `HandlerInterceptor`s will actually break `POST-redirect-GET` components that were handwritten.

The alternative would be to check which handler is being used in each `HandlerInterceptor` method, but this is hardly DRY, is also error-prone, and I cannot make this adjustment on classes like `OpenSessionInViewInterceptor` without extending them. The solution I came up with to avoid all this mess was to use a separate servlet specifically for static(ish) resources.

Comment: Why you insist on splitting this to two `DispatcherServlets`?

Comment: Btw. to solve your issue just map your servlet to `/resources` path.

Comment: It would take too long to explain the need for two `DispatcherServlet`s; just know that it has to be that way. Also, `/resources` cannot be used here as the resources are in directories at the app root.

Comment: It does not matter where they are... the path used in mapping will be stripped when looking for the resource by Spring. You just need to referr to them as `/resources/js/foo.js` from your HTML / JSP.

Comment: There are too many locations to change for that. The paths in my HTML are `/my-app/css/foo.css` and the like.

Comment: Then you need to set `#setAlwaysUseFullPath(true)` on the `SimpleUrlHandlerMapping` registered by `<mvc:resources>`. You can either register all components manually (might be better) or you need to post-process the created instances.

Comment: That seems like the route I'm going down. If you want to put an answer in I'll give you credit for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## The simple solution

First, I feel like I have to write the obvious (if not for OP, then for others who might read this answer in the future):

- The simple solution would be to just use single `DispatcherServlet`. If there is not a very strong reason, do not use two servlets.
- Alternatively you can map your resources to `/resources/*` path. It is a common (best?) practice to have all resources under a well defined path.

## The complex solution

Now `<mvc:resources>` is processed by [`ResourcesBeanDefinitionParser`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/4.0.x/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/ResourcesBeanDefinitionParser.java). This component registers two crucial components: `SimpleUrlHandlerMapping` and `ResourceHttpRequestHandler`.

The first component is responsible for mapping requests to the handler. If you don't want this component to [strip servlet mapping path](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/4.0.x/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/handler/SimpleUrlHandlerMapping.java#L46), you need to set the [alwaysUseFullPath flag](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/handler/AbstractHandlerMapping.html#setAlwaysUseFullPath-boolean-). This can be done either by doing `<mvc:resources>` configuration yourself, or by post processing the registered instances.

For the manual configuration using the example in the question, set up the mappings and handlers:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="lesscss" />

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">
  <property name="alwaysUseFullPath" value="true" />
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
  <property name="alwaysUseFullPath" value="true"/>
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter" />

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
  <property name="alwaysUseFullPath" value="true"/>
  <property name="mappings">
    <props>
      <prop key="/images/**">imagesResources</prop>
      <prop key="/js/**">jsResources</prop>
    </props>
  </property>
</bean>

<bean id="imagesResources" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler">
  <property name="locations">
    <list>
      <value>/images/</value>
    </list>
  </property>
</bean>

<bean id="jsResources" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler">
  <property name="locations">
    <list>
      <value>/js/</value>
    </list>
  </property>
</bean>
```

For the post-processing approach, create and register bean:

```
public class SimpleUrlMappingConfigurer implements BeanPostProcessor {

    @Override
    public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) {
        return bean;
    }

    @Override
    public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) {
        if (bean instanceof SimpleUrlHandlerMapping) {
            ((SimpleUrlHandlerMapping) bean).setAlwaysUseFullPath(true);
        }
        return bean;
    }

}
```

Comment: Added my two-servlet explanation for clarity and perspective.